# Factorial sign before a number

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, definition, factorial

Is there a standard definition for $!n$ like $n!$?
The definition of $n!,n!!,n!!!,\ldots$ is very is easy to find. but I can't find anything about $!n$.
for example, $$5!=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\\9!!=1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot9$$
but, does it mean? $$!5=\text{?}\\!3=\text{?}\\ \vdots$$ can someone help me, or show me a reference? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you see this being used?

Comment: Thanks for the response, one of my student's asked me. He was a good student, that I think its a serious question

Comment: It's about derangements! Also we have the beautiful approximation
$$!n \approx \dfrac{n!}{e}$$
where $e$ is the Euler number.

Comment: @Turing This means that derangements are about $37\%$ of the $n$-combinations

Comment: @Turing AFAIK the symbol $n?$ doesn't exist in math. Do you confirm?

Comment: @Raffaele Yes! Consider that this approximation holds as $n\to +\infty$ (indeed it's the exact limit: as $n$ goes to infinity, $\frac{!n}{n!} \to \frac{1}{e}$. It's amazing!

Comment: @Raffaele I once found something about Minkowski that will amuse and amaze you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_question-mark_function :)

Comment: @Turing Amazing! This reminds me of the shortest communication ever. A opera composer, maybe Rossini, had to leave the country the day before the premiere of his last opera. So the day after he sent a telegram to the theatrical manager "?" and the manager answered "!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notation of a preceding exclamation point can represent the [subfactorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) (a.k.a. [derangement](https://oeis.org/A000166) number).  In this usage,
\begin{align*}
!0 &= 1  \\
!1 &= 0  \\
!n &= (n-1)(!(n-1) + !(n-2)), n > 1  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew about the derangement, but not about "!" use in this case. Thank you again.